# How to split a cell by letter case/parenthesis/number

Tags: excel, split

I have a dictionary in excel in which one complete dictionary entry occupies one cell. I would like to split this cell into two cells, the first being Language 1, the second being Language 2.

Here is an example of the dictionary:

---

A 1. the male or positive principle, yang 2. convex, raised 3. interjection of response 4. interjection of fear 5. vocative particle 6. a tooth in the Manchu script

A A an interjection of casual response

A I BUKDAN the outside edge of a piece of folded paper

A JIJUN I ACANGGA a bronze identification token with raised characters used to gain admittance to a city at night

A JILGAN a yang tone in music

A FA SERE ONGGOLO see afanggala

A SI a sound used for driving chickens or birds

A TA (onom.) the sound of a commotion

---

The output I desire:

---

```
A                 | 1. the male or positive principle, yang 2. convex,
A A               | an interjection of casual response 
A I BUKDAN        | the outside edge of a piece of folded paper 
A JIJUN I ACANGGA | a bronze identification token with raised characters 
A JILGAN          | a yang tone in music 
A FA SERE ONGGOLO | see afanggala 
A SI              | a sound used for driving chickens or birds
A TA              | (onom.) the sound of a commotion
```

I would need a few conditions in splitting these cells. the split would need to occur either before the first occuring number in each entry (as in the first entry), before the first lower case letter, or before a "("

splitting it after the final uppercase letter in an entry would probably not work because upper case letters exist in the "Language 2" column as well.

Is this possible? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use Excel for this purpose.  Instead, I would split your data first and then import into Excel.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How do you suggest I split it prior? the biggest issue is that I have over 20,000 entries and no time to do it by hand

Comment: For starters, you should also show what output you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen good point, I will edit the original question

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated, thanks for taking your time to look at this!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SeparateUpperCase()
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    total = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
    For i = 1 To total
'assume the input is in the 1st column and put output in 2nd and 3rd columns
        count = GetUpperCaseNum(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1))
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = Trim(Left(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), count))
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) = Trim(Right(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), Len(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)) - count))
    Next
End Sub

Function GetUpperCaseNum(str As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim A As Integer, Z As Integer, Space As Integer
    Dim tmp As Integer

    A = Asc("A")
    Z = Asc("Z")
    Space = Asc(" ")

    result = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        tmp = Asc(Mid(str, i, 1))
        If Not (tmp >= A And tmp <= Z Or tmp = Space) Then 'just count UpperCase and Space
            result = i - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    GetUpperCaseNum = result
End Function
```